# AngularJS Router invoke function when certain URL is loaded initially

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using angular router` to track the state of my web app like this:

```
when('/', {
    controller: "AController",
    templateUrl: "APanel.html"
}).
when('/subpage/:id', {
    controller: "BController",
    templateUrl: "BPanel.html"
}).
```

And I am using `Angular Service` to track some shared values:

```
app.service('stateService', function() {
    this.someSwitch = false;
    this.someLongDataArray = [x, y, z];
});
```

Currently, before changing path to `\subpage\:id` url from `AController`, I will assign new values to members of the service, so they can be referenced in subpages.

**Now the question is**, if user directly launching the subpage url `\subpage\:id`, or hit the refresh button on browser on subpage, BController will be invoked, and I will lost the values in the service which are supposed to be prepared by AController.

I am wondering what I should do in this case. is there any way I can get called when user launch the subpage directly, so I have a chance to prepare the data? (Maybe I can watch for html onload event, but not sure that's the best answer).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It appears, BController is dependent on AController.
Ideally, Controller should not contain any data/dom manipulaton, state maintenance. It is simply a glue between view and the $scope model.
Being said so, you need not create any such dependency between controllers. The service can be invoked from both controllers.

**OR**
If indeed there is a requirement that APanel.html must be loaded/initialized before BPanel.html is loaded, then you must check for some flag in BContoller and redirect user to APanel.html.
like

```
if(<check some flag>){
 $location.path('/');
}
```

But then you have to find the way to redirect the user again to BPanel.html. I guess this is not a recommended approach.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I get your question completely. But if there is a possibility that the user might hit `BPanel.html` directly then you should do something like this.

```
if(serviceExists()){
    //Do your usual Bcontroller stuff here if the services was initialized 
}
else{
    //Show a warning/error like "Oops, something is wrong go back to '/'" OR
    // Initialize services in BController

}
```

This should be in your BController if initializing your service before BController is that important. You basically force people to stay on AController.

Comment: Thank you, but I am not sure where this code should be placed? Should this code be placed in `$scope.someFunction(){...}` in BController? Or some other place that will be called when the controller is loaded?

Comment: the Bcontroller should be called whenever the route is loaded. So inside your BController code you should check before anything.